# Save Recent Location History Google Maps API With Auto Complete Search Location

Tags: flutter, google-maps

recently I use `flutter_google_places` to auto complete search location but I think theres no component in it to save recent location as image below. I'm thinking to create my own by saving it on shared preferences. Is there any better way to do that like package or do google maps api provides that?

[image: maps history]

Comment: You should set your expectation first that the Google Maps App and the Google Maps API are different platforms. So there's would be somehow a difference in the functionalities. Then I don't think the Places Autocomplete provides such functionality since the Places Autocomplete is mainly for helping users with their ambiguous queries. Not for saving recent searches. I guess it could be possible to programmatically store recent search place IDs and show it on the search box but I haven't tried that yet. You should have a custom search box for this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yap, I have search Google Maps API documentation but didn't find out for those. Just wondering if theres any best way for that. But at this time I'll try store recent search locally.